# How to change the request done by autocomplete and add data from another text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need to add the value from another element into the request of the auto complete.

Here are the fields:

[image]
This is the js code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sub_category_select_add_product_page").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
             console.log(request);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/autocomplete/' + request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data_sub_category_modal) {

                    response($.map(data_sub_category_modal, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Product_Category_Name,
                            id: item.id
                        };
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#sub_category_select_add_product_page").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#sub_category_select_add_product_page").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#sub_category_id").val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        },
        change: function() {
            alert('changed');
        }
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
                .append("<div>" + item.label + "</div>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

This is my form:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-level"><label>Product Category <b class="mandetory_star">*</b> :</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="category_select_add_product_page">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_select_add_product_page-id">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCategory">
            Add Category
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-level"><label>Product Sub Category <b class="mandetory_star">*</b> :</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="sub_category_select_add_product_page">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="sub_category_id" id="sub_category_select_add_product_page-id">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSubCategory">
            Add Sub Category
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I put the value of

> *#category_select_add_product_page-id*

into the

> *url: 'api/autocomplete/' + request.term,*

This is the field:

```
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_select_add_product_page-id">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.term` is the value that was typed inside the `input` field that has the autocomplete. If you want to add more information besides this value you can just change the `url` according to the value you need:

```
url: 'api/autocomplete/' + $('#category_select_add_product_page-id').val() + ' ' + request.term,
```